# UICollectionView showing 2 items instead of 3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

I have implemented my `UICollectionView` like this

```
extension MyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photos.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .black
        return cell
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let widthPerItem = view.frame.width / 3
        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
    }
}
```

but instead of 3 items in a row I'm getting 2 items
[image]

how can i fix it? i didn't set any `UIEdgeInset` for my items and sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your screan width can not fit 3 cells. This is because collection view has cell min line spacing property in your storyboard if you try with small width in sizeForItemAt they will fit.

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let widthPerItem = view.frame.width / 3 - ((collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.minimumInterItemSpacing ?? 0.0)
        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
    }
```

Comment: In your method sizeForItemAt you set other minimum size. Change this size and it will work. Because if you implement this method values from this method are preferd than these from storyboard

Comment: Will this even compile? You're trying to subtract `Optional<CGFloat>` from `CGFloat`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to account for `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` properties of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` - they both default to `10.0` if you didn't set them.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let spacing : CGFloat = (collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.minimumInteritemSpacing ?? 0.0
    let widthPerItem = (view.frame.width  - spacing * 2)/ 3
    return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
extension MyViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let numRowItems:CGFloat = 3
        let padding:CGFloat = 2
        let width = (collectionView.bounds.width / numRowItems) - padding 
        let height = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * padding)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in obj c

```
 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//If you want your cell should be square in size the return the equal height and width, and make sure you deduct the Section Inset from it.
return CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - 16, (self.view.frame.size.width/2) - 16);
}
```

swift

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
// Compute the dimension of a cell for an NxN layout with space S between
// cells.  Take the collection view's width, subtract (N-1)*S points for
// the spaces between the cells, and then divide by N to find the final
// dimension for the cell's width and height.

let cellsAcross: CGFloat = 3
let spaceBetweenCells: CGFloat = 1
let dim = (collectionView.bounds.width - (cellsAcross - 1) * spaceBetweenCells) / cellsAcross
return CGSize(width: dim, height: dim)
}
```